# What's the best static analysis tool for NetBeans 6.1?

Tags: netbeans, plugins

I'm finding a couple for Java in general but no plugins for netbeans that I can see.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the [PMD NetBeans plugin](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=56262&package_id=63621), and [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html#netbeans) are the installation instructions (may be a little outdated, due to the speed of NetBeans development, but I got them to work).

Here's a list of [tools for static analyisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java_2).  Maybe you can cross-check for others that offer NetBeans support.

**EDIT:** Those instruction are a little bit old, so I put a more up-to-date set [here](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2008/11/netbeans-pmd-plugin.html) (links to my blog).

Answer (score 0):

I found the [SQE Plugin](https://sqe.dev.java.net/), it integrates FindBugs, CheckStyle and PMD into one convenient Plugin.

CheckStyle configuration was not complete yet, but the functionality is there in full.